# Java: Issue building a zoo using inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

I am new to Java and I'm having an issue with inheritance. I'm working through an activity where I have a parent class (Animal) and child classes (Giraffe in this instance) which inherits the fields of the parent class. I was instructed to have a default constructor and a constructor that accepts parameters in both instances of the parent and child classes.

The issue that I'm encountering is that when I run printInfo() it is returning the default for species in the parent's default constructor ('species') and not the child class ('giraffe'). I had assumed that the Giraffe child class would inherit this parent class method, but it seems that something's not quite right here.

(Note that each of my classes are separate files)

Any assistance or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

```
// Parent class:

public class Animal {
    String name;
    String species;
    int age;

    // default constructor
    public Animal() {
    name = "name";
    species = "species";
    age = 0;
    }
    
    // constructor w/ parameters
    public Animal(String name, String species, int age){
        this.name = name;
        this.species = species;
        this.age = age;
    }
    
    // method for printing out animal info
            void printInfo() {
            System.out.println(name + ", " + species + ", " + age);
    }
    
} 

// Child class:

public class Giraffe extends Animal {
    String species = "giraffe";
    
    // default giraffe constructor
    public Giraffe() {
        super();
        name  = "Errol";
        age = 0;
    }

    // giraffe constructor with parameters
    public Giraffe(String name, int age) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    
}

// Main class (calls printInfo method from Animal parent class)

public class ZooBuilder {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Giraffe one = new Giraffe("Mark", 23);

        one.printInfo();

    }
}


Prints: *Mark, species, 23*
```

Comment: `species` is not a method; it's a field. If you want to be able to override a thing, you need it to be a method. `String getSpecies() { ... }`

Comment: You can't override fields. Do not re-declare the species field.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo: Thank for the comment. For clarity, when I refer to the method I meant the getInfo() method and not the species field, in case there was any confusion there.

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter : Is that in reference to redeclaring the species field in the Giraffe class? If so, I'm uncertain how I can specify the species field for each child class?

Answer (score 1):

Change the Giraffe constructor to call the full constructor

```
public Giraffe(String name, int age) {
    super(name, "Giraffe", age);
}
```

Change the default to also be like the above

Comment: Marvellous, worked perfectly - thank you!